# std::tuple_element and references

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple

I study std::tuple.

Let's we have:

```
struct test_struct{};
```

I write

```
std::cout << typeid(std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<struct test_struct &>>).name();
```

And I was expecting the type

```
struct test_struct &
```

But I received:

```
struct test_struct
```

How I can extract type **struct test_struct &** (preferably using std11)?

Thanks.

Comment: `typeid` strips references, i.e. `typeid(int&) == typeid(int)`. The real question is, *why do you want this*? If you supplied that (that is, some MVCE), we could diagnose why it isn't behaving as expected. But for now, it seems everything is as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `typeid` operator does not *work* for reference types,

> §5.2.8/4-5
> If *type* is a reference type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the referenced type.
>
> In all cases, cv-qualifiers are ignored by typeid (that is, `typeid(T)==typeid(const T)`)

you can write few wrappers to find out names of reference types or types with cv-qualifiers.

```
template<typename T>
struct typeid_hlp
{
    static std::string name() { return typeid(T).name(); }
};

template<typename T>
struct typeid_hlp<T&>
{
    static std::string name() { return typeid_hlp<T>::name() + std::string(" &"); }
};

template<typename T>
struct typeid_hlp<T&&>
{
    static std::string name() { return typeid_hlp<T>::name() + std::string(" &&"); }
};

template<typename T>
struct typeid_hlp<const T>
{
    static std::string name() { return std::string("const ") + typeid_hlp<T>::name(); }
};

template<typename T>
struct typeid_hlp<volatile T>
{
    static std::string name() { return std::string("volatile ") + typeid_hlp<T>::name(); }
};
```

And use it like

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid_hlp<int>::name() << std::endl; // int
    std::cout << typeid_hlp<int&>::name() << std::endl; // int &
    std::cout << typeid_hlp<const int>::name() << std::endl; // const int
    std::cout << typeid_hlp<volatile const int * const &>::name() << std::endl; // const int const volatile * __ptr64 &
}
```

Comment: Thanks . I right understand that from tuple_element_t I receive right reference type, its only output problem that I don't see reference?

Comment: @JDiOrEximen Yes, `typeid` strips const modifiers and reference modifiers.